# what is the remainder when $1!+2!+3!+4!+\cdots+45!$ is divided by 47?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

Can any one please tell the approach or solve the question

> what is the remainder when $1!+2!+3!+4!+\cdots+45!$ is divided by $47$?

I can solve remainder of $45!$ divided by $47$ using Wilson's theorem but I don't know what must be the approach for this model problems, as $47$ is a prime number I cannot convert it into another factorial and divide.

If any one of you viewing have any idea regarding the approach, please post your approach here.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pavan Kumar

Comment: Possible first hint: $\binom{46}{k}\equiv (-1)^k\pmod {47}$

Comment: Use Wilson's theorem to relate $k!$ and $(47-k)!$ ($\mod{47}$).

Comment: Have you tried to calculate this remainder for "smaller values of 47"? I.e., 47 is prime, try to calculate this first for 5, 7, 11, 13, etc.

Comment: Hint: Consider the series expansion for $\frac{1}{e}$. By doing this, you can show that $1! + 2! + \cdots + (p-1)!$ is congruent to $\frac{p-1}{e}$ mod $p$ (I forget if you need to round up or down) for arbitrary primes $p$. Now you get what you want from Wilson.

Comment: But what is $\,e\pmod p\;$ ??

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo Is there a trick there? I don't see a pattern...

Comment: @Cocopuffs not really, I don't see a pattern either, but if the OP knows how to calculate it quickly for 17 say, should be able to do it for 47.

Comment: It gets pretty messy already after a few calculations (and I focused on primes $\;=3\pmod 4\;$ : for $\,p=7\,$ we get $\,-1\,$ , for $\,p=11\,$ I got $\,4\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant to round before doing the mod (I can see I did not make that very clear). Unfortunately, I wrote that rather hastily because I had to go, and now I can't fill in the details myself (and I seem to have misremembered some of the details, as it does not seem to fit my calculation for small primes).

Comment: Not even the online integer database gives a shortcut: https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+1%2C+0%2C+1%2C+3%2C+3%2C+5%2C+1&language=english&go=Search

Comment: A google search concerning "left factorial" and "modulus" brings up several results on Kurepa's Conjecture, all of which suggest that reducing this computation to polynomial time is unsolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to compose table:

\begin{array}{|c|r|}
\hline
n! & \equiv \ldots (\bmod \:47) \\
\hline \\
1! & 1 \\
2! & 2\cdot 1 = 2 \\
3! & 3 \cdot 2 = 6 \\
4! & 4 \cdot 6 = 24 \\
5! & 5 \cdot 24 = 120 \equiv 26 \\
6! & 6 \cdot 26 = 156 \equiv 15 \\
7! & 7 \cdot 15 = 105 \equiv 11 \\ 
\cdots \\
44! & 44 \cdot 8 = 352 \equiv 23 \\
45! & 45 \cdot 23 = 1035 \equiv 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

$45$ steps/rows in total.

Then to find sum:
$S = 1+2+6+24+26+15+11+\ldots+23+1 = \color{#E0E0E0}{1052 \equiv 18 (\bmod \: 47)}$.

---

Here we use idea: 
if $\qquad$ $k! \equiv s (\bmod \: p)$, 
then $\;$ $(k+1)! \equiv (k+1)\cdot s (\bmod \: p)$,
and apply it step-by-step.

Comment: What is there in the three dots? All the residues modulo $\;47\;$ but $\,-1\\,$? If yes, why?

Comment: Unless you calculate exactly *all* the elements $\,k!\pmod {47}\,$ , I can't see how can you know what the sum of the factorials are. Is this calculation what you're proposing to do?

Comment: @DonAntonio:: I think: let author of question calculate all elements $k!(\bmod \: 47)$, and later to add them all. My answer is: grayed "18". It is not so hard: 45 rows in the table, and 45 terms in the sum.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I got your first question :) . No, I don't see any rule/pattern in remainders. $8! \equiv 16! \equiv 29! \equiv 41 \mod 47$; and there are no remainders $3,5,7,9,10, \ldots$.

Comment: Oh, I know it is not hard...but it's terribly annoying and dull! Perhaps this is what the OP wanted to know, but I seriously doubt this will help him if instead $\,47\,$ her had $\,103\,$ or some other bigger prime...

Answer (score 4):

If you write the sum backwards you get

$45! + 44! + 43! + ... + 1! = (((···(45+1)44+1)43+1)···+1)2+1$

This creates the sequence

$t_0 = 45, \quad t_{n+1} = (t_n+1)(t_0-n)$

where we wish to find the value of $t_{44}$

This will take $44$ multiplications and $88$ additions, which seems pretty efficient.

Doing the arithmetic modulo $47$, I got $t_{44} \equiv 18 \pmod{47}$.

```
 n  t[n]     n  t[n]     n  t[n]     n  t[n]     n  t[n]
 0    45     9    44    18    38    27    46    36    18
 1     3    10    24    19    27    28     0    37    11
 2    31    11     4    20    42    29    16    38    37
 3    28    12    24    21    45    30    20    39    40
 4    14    13     1    22    24    31    12    40    17
 5    36    14    15    23    33    32    28    41    25
 6    33    15    10    24     9    33    19    42    31
 7    23    16    37    25    12    34    32    43    17
 8    42    17    30    26    12    35     1    44    18
```