# What is the remainder left after dividing $1! + 2! + 3! + ... + 100!$ by $5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

I have this question as a homework.

> What is the remainder left after dividing $1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + 100!$ by $5$?

I tried this: I noticed that every $n! \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ for every $n\geq 5$.

For $n < 5$:

$$\begin{align*}
1! &\equiv 1 \pmod{5} \\
2! &\equiv 2 \pmod{5} \\
3! &\equiv 1 \pmod{5} \\
4! &\equiv 4 \pmod{5} \\
\end{align*}$$

So $1! + 2! + \cdots + 100! \equiv 8 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$.
Therefore the remainder is $3$. 
Am I thinking properly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Equivalently: if you notice that $3!+4!=30$, that means you only need to add $1!$ and $2!$.

Comment: This is not to say that the above question is bad (it's not! it's well-posed, clearly stated, with good effort shown), but I'm curious as to why it has so many upvotes in such a short time, when so often similarly good questions languish. Can anyone shed light? Maybe it's just the Festivus spirit.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Let me guess. Perhaps, it is because there are quite amount of ugly written,  ill-posed, post-without-showing-any-effort questions on this site, while this one is written nicely due to Zev's edit and shows the effort .

Comment: @PatrickStevens Some questions just get popular while others don't. It depends on the luck not the level of question.

Answer (score 3):

To complement the other answer in less theory-heavy terms, you can view it as:

$$1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! (1 + 6 + [6 \times 7] + \dots + [6 \times \dots \times 100])$$

The final term is clearly divisible by $5$; so we just need to look at $1! + 2! + 3! + 4!$ and its remainder, as you did.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of an answer:

YES. You are thinking properly. What you did is nice and correct.

<s>Similar</s> Related questions:

[What is the remainder when $1! + 2! + 3! +\cdots+ 1000!$ is divided by $12$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/618992/9464)

[what is the remainder when $1!+2!+3!+4!+\cdots+45!$ is divided by 47?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440717/what-is-the-remainder-when-1234-cdots45-is-divided-by-47?rq=1)

Comment: And you are right to not make this cw: it took some precious time to write this down, so here's your upvote.

Comment: I agree the first link is similar, but the second link is different: 47 is a prime number, and we only sum factorials of smaller numbers than 47, so none of them "cancel out" automatically. This means that other techniques are needed to approach the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are right.

Notice that the unit digit of the sum is $3$, because all the terms in the sum end up with a zero from $5!$ and hence to find the unit digit, we just need to find the unit digit of the sum $1!+2!+3!+4!=33$ which is $3$.

So, when the sum $1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + 100!$ is divided by $5$, it leaves a remainder $3$.